# Canvas,Multiple Rectangle,Rotation

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I have A CanVas In Which I Add Sevral Rectangles.I can Add Text In A Rectangle Which Is Selected Now.I Have Also Implement Sevral Other Functionalities In Selected Rectangle Like Drag Them,Resize Them.But Now My Task Is To Rotate A Rectangle Which Is Selected Now.Can Any One Suggest How To Do That so that my Resizing Functionalitiy also Work With Rotation Simultanously. I want to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your rectangle definitions in javascript objects & put the rect-objects in an array:

```
var rects=[];
rects.push({
    x:50,y:50,
    w:50,h:35,
    color:'green',
    angle:0,deltaAngle:(Math.PI*2)/60,
    scale:100,scaleDirection:1}
);
rects.push({
    x:150,y:50,
    w:50,h:35,
    color:'blue',
    angle:0,deltaAngle:(Math.PI*2)/60,
    scale:100,scaleDirection:1}
);
```

Then you can draw your rectangles with your transforms (move, rotate, scale) in a for-next loop:

Iterate the array and draw each rectangle: `for( var i=0; i<rects.length; i++)`

- **Save** the untransformed context state.
- **Translate** to the center of the rectangle. The [0,0] origin is now at the rect's centerpoint.
- **Scale** to the specified scale factor.
- **Rotate** to the specified angle.
- **Draw the rectangle**.  Since the origin is at the rect's center, offset the drawing by -width/2, -height/2.
- **Restore** the context to its untransformed state.

Illustrations of the results:

[image][image]

**[Addition: get mouse angle]**

You can get the angle of the mouse vs the any rect's centerpoint like this:

```
var dx=mouseX-centerX;
var dy=mouseY-centerY;
var radianAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
```

Comment: ,,,,Thanku Mark For Your Reply. I am Doing This Work As You Suggested Like Using an Array and Pushing Data For Different Rectangles... Problem Is I Need To Get Angle Dynamically and I Dont Know How To Get That In JavaScript.I have 8 Points Around My Every Rectangle.Means These Points Are Small Rectangles From Where at Mouse Down Event I Want To Rotate The Currently Selected Rectangle.I am New To This Site and Dont know How To Show You My Code.

Comment: function addRect(x, y, w, h, fill,text,FontSize,TextColor,TextFontFamily,Angle,ScaleWidth,ScaleHeight) {
        var rect = new Box2;
        rect.x = x;
        rect.y = y;
        rect.w = w
        rect.h = h;
        rect.Owntext = text;
        rect.FontSize = FontSize;
        rect.TextColor = TextColor;
        rect.TextFontFamily = TextFontFamily;
        rect.Angle = Angle;
        rect.ScaleWidth = ScaleWidth;
        rect.ScaleHeight = ScaleHeight;
     
     

      //  alert(fill);

        rect.fill = fill;
        boxes2.push(rect);
        invalidate();
    }

Comment: function mainDraw() {
    //    alert('MainDraw');
        if (canvasValid == false) {
            clear(ctx);
          var l = boxes2.length;
          
            var font = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                var x = boxes2[i].x;
                var y = boxes2[i].y;
                var w = boxes2[i].w;

Comment: var h = boxes2[i].h;
              ctx.translate(0,0);
                ctx.rotate(boxes2[i].Angle);
                //If You Want to Change This x and y  values By Adding Another Number Do The Same In The  ****switch (expectResize) *** 
                var Textx = boxes2[i].x ;
                var Texty = boxes2[i].y + boxes2[i].h / 1.4;
                ctx.textAlign = "Start";
                ctx.fillStyle = boxes2[i].TextColor;//This Is For Text Color Of A RectAngle

Comment: ctx.font =  boxes2[i].FontSize + 'pt '+ boxes2[i].TextFontFamily;
                ctx.fillText(boxes2[i].Owntext, Textx, Texty, boxes2[i].w);
                boxes2[i].draw(ctx);
             
            }

Comment: See the addition to my answer showing how you can get the radian angle of the mouse vs any rectangle's centerpoint. Then just plug that angle into `context.rotate(theRadianAngle)`. Cheers!